# I can't manage positioning of divs in css and html

Tags: html, css

i'm creating a website and adding divs. the problem is my main div, which is container, is not following the number of divs inside of it. the divs inside it keeps on overlapping on to it and do not follow container. help me find the problem. thanks.
below is my code:

for my css:

```
.container{
position: relative;
height: 100%;

margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
max-width: 1100px;
background-color: #fff;
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 6px 7px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 7px #ccc;
box-shadow:         0px 0px 6px 7px #ccc;

}

.cities{
position: relative;
top: 110px;

}

.top{
position: relative; 
top: 120px; left: 25px;
max-width: 500px;
}
```

for my html:

```
        <div class="container" >

            <div class="cities">
                <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">Kwiktable Makati
                <a href="#" style="color: black; float: right; margin-right: 5px; ">Mandaluyong </a> <a href="#"style="color: black;float: right;margin-right: 5px; ">Pasig </a> <a href="#"style="color: black;float: right;margin-right: 5px; ">Quezon city </a> <a href="#"style="color: black;float: right;margin-right: 5px; ">Taguig </a></p>
            </div>
                <hr style="position: relative; top: 120px; width: 1060px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
            <div class="top">
                <?php include'content1.html';?>
            </div>
            <hr class="middle" style="position: relative; top: -300px;"/>
            <div class="best">
                <h1 style="position: relative; width: 350px; left: 50px; height: 80px; color: #fff; text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000;"><span style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 40px">

                Kwiktable's Best!</span></h1>
                <?php include'best.php';?>

            </div>
```

here is whats happening: http://tinypic.com/r/o69qqe/8

Comment: first things first, stop mixing inline styles and stylesheets. move everything to the stylesheet and you'll have an easier time. What do you mean by `.container` doesn't "follow" the divs inside it. What do you want it to look like?

Comment: i want to put an image but stackoverflow won't let me they said i need to have at least 10 reputation points... anyways what i wanted is the container would contain all the divs inside it so whenever i add another div the container will only just expand

Comment: Things are overlapping because you are setting positions on top of one another. Why explicitly position everything?

Comment: i am trying to add html pages on my php page. its kinda hacker-slow-him-down thing.

Comment: @user3690039 - if you want to add an image, you can add the URL of the image into the text of your question, and add a note asking a higher-rep user to add it to the question on your behalf.

Comment: i've added the url of my picture

Answer (score 0):

Try positioning your div's with `margin` and `padding` instead of `top` and `left`. As is, they only occupy as much space as they would if there were no (positional) styling on them. So it's not that your `.container` isn't containing, you just can't tell.
If you instead of using `top:125px` use `padding-top:125px` your container will expand. because the container will see the element as taking up all that space. (execpt in the case of floats, then you would need to clear them.)

Comment: i just can't find the problem. it sitll doing the same thing

Comment: is the stuff you are adding `float:left`?

Answer (score 0):

use

`position:absolute;
top:100px; etc`